# Best practice to archive less frequent accessed data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have an e-commerce application running on MySQL server from last 10 years. There are particularly two tables:

- orders (Apporx 30 million rows and 3 GB data)
- order_item (Approx 45 million rows and 3.5 GB data)

These tables contain all orders and their respective products purchased in last 10 years. Generally last 6 months data is most frequently accessed and all previous data is either used in multiple reports by business/marketing teams or if a customer checks his order history

As this table constantly growing in size we are running into increased query time for both read and write. Therefore, I was wondering to archive some data from these tables to improve performance.  Main concern is that archived data should still be available for reads by reports and customers.

What would be a right archiving strategy for this?

Comment: Instead of archiving it, consider moving the old data to another database server that can be used for generating reports.  Or to another database schema on the same server.

Comment: There is no "best practice".  Best practice implies that there is a single best solution for all circumstances.  Clearly that is not the case for you.  And you don't want a "best practice".  You want a solution that meets >your< requirements, not everyone's.

Comment: First see if "innodb_file_per_table" is set to 1 in your config. if not set you must set it and recreate your tables :-(. Second, use "Partitioning  Table" there you can split the table into pieces like years. Then you can use the hole table or a piece of it. MySQL holds the a sep. INDEX for each partition: see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html

Comment: @BerndBuffen - The separate index per partition is rarely any better than a suitably rearranged index.  I give one example of such in [_Partition_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)

Answer (score 0):

**PARTITIONing** is unlikely to provide any performance benefit.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and some of the "slow" queries so I can analyze the access patterns, clustered index choice, the potential for Partitioning, etc.

Sometimes a change to the PK (which is "**clustered**" with the data) can greatly improve the "locality of reference", which provides performance benefits.  A user going back in time may also blow out the cache (the "buffer pool).  Changing the PK to *start with* `user_id` may significantly improve on that issue.

Another possibility is to use **replication** to segregate "read-only" queries that go back in time from the "active" records (read/write in the last few months).  This can benefit by decreasing the I/O by having customers on the Primary while relegating the "reports" to a Replica.

How much **RAM**?  When the data gets "big", running a "report" may blow out the cache, making everything be slower.  **Summary table(s)** is a very good cure for such.

The **optimal indexes** for a Partitioned table are necessarily different than for the equivalent non-partitioned table.